# Trouble understanding extra-assembly instructions generated by code

Tags: assembly

I'm studying the book Computer Systems: A Programmers Perspective. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding problem 3.5:

> You are given the following information. A function with prototype

```
void decode1(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp);
```

> is compiled into assembly code. The body of the code is as follows:
>
> xp at %ebp+8, yp at %ebp+12, zp at %ebp+16

```
1 movl 8(%ebp), %edi

2 movl 12(%ebp), %edx

3 movl 16(%ebp), %ecx

4 movl (%edx), %ebx

5 movl (%ecx), %esi

6 movl (%edi), %eax

7 movl %eax, (%edx)

8 movl %ebx, (%ecx)

9 movl %esi, (%edi)
```

> Parameters xp, yp, and zp are stored at memory locations with offsets
>   8, 12, and 16, respectively, relative to the address in register %ebp.
>   Write C code for decode1 that will have an effect equivalent to the
>   assembly code above.

I came up with the following c function:

```
void decode1(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp) {
    int *a = yp;
    int *b = zp;
    int *c = xp;

    yp = c;
    zp = a;
    xp = b;
}
```

Compiling to assembly (flags: -w32 -O0 -S) I get the following assembly code:

```
decode1(int*, int*, int*):
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $16, %esp
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp) // ??
movl    16(%ebp), %eax   
movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)  // ??
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)  // ??
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 12(%ebp)
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 16(%ebp)
movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, 8(%ebp)
nop
leave
ret
```

I have two questions:

Is my C code correct? And if it is, why the difference in assembly code? I don't understand why the code seems to be storing the variables back into memory and then loading them back? Why is it using only %eax? I have 6 variables so it should be able to load them in the 6 registers, no?

---

EDIT: Generated code with -O2 instead of -O0

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
subl    $24, %esp
movl    16(%ebp), %eax
movl    12(%ebp), %ecx
movl    8(%ebp), %edx
movl    %edx, -4(%ebp)
movl    %ecx, -8(%ebp)
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
movl    -12(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -20(%ebp)
movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -24(%ebp)
movl    -24(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
movl    -16(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
movl    -20(%ebp), %eax
movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
addl    $24, %esp
popl    %ebp
retl
```

---

EDIT2: correct answer is actually:

```
    void decode1(int *xp, int *yp, int *zp) {
    int a = *yp;
    int b = *zp;
    int c = *xp;

    *yp = c;
    *zp = a;
    *xp = b;
}
```

Comment: With -O0 in effect, the compiler generates code that is easy to debug but is not optimal.  The optimizer gets rid of the redundant stores.

Comment: Hmmmmm so that's why it only uses %eax? Well, other than that, do you think the C function translates to the assembly instructions from the problem?

Comment: Withouth the -O0 it still generates the same code...

Comment: You've discovered what the default value is for -O if you don't specify it explicitly.  Learned another thing.

Comment: @HansPassant I see, nice to know. Do you think the function I wrote is the correct answer?

Comment: The code generated is providing offsets. The first 2 lines are the `assembly prolog` (preserving the callers base pointer address setting the current routines stack as the base pointer). The next line `$16, %esp` reserves space for your local variables/pointers. Your `??` lines are storing the local variables in the reserved space. the `-x` is just a relative offset of where to put each variable relative to the current stack pointer. The masm/ATT syntax is a bit different than I'm used to, but it appears to be doing the swap correctly. Compile with `-O2` next.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see. I posted the code generated with -O2. Is uses 3 registers but then it goes back to storing them and loading them only in EAX. Well, what really matters for me is if the C function I wrote is the correct answer for the question. It seems to be, so for me that's good enough. I'll read more of the book so I understand the stack frame better. Thank you for you help David and Hans.

Comment: Why don't you compile with compiler warnings? Your compiler should have told you that your function is garbage. You're confusing `int` and `int*` all over.

Comment: @EOF Thanks, fixed it. I don't really program in C... Kinda weird you need to turn compile warnings on to see those, and it's not that way by default.

Comment: Yeah, for gcc I've gotten used to *always* compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3`. The `-O3` is important, by the way, as gcc only recognises some problems when optimizing.